# How long was the longest given extra time in a half in football?

Tags: football

While watching a World Cup game, I noticed how the extra time given at the end of the first half is usually shorter than the extra time given at the end of the second half. That led me to wonder what was the longest extra time awarded at a football game, and after some reasearch I found this Bristol City game in 2000-2001 in a [The Guardian article](https://www.theguardian.com/football/2006/nov/29/theknowledge.sport), where apparently 23 minutes of extra time were added:

> "When Brentford played away at Bristol City in 2000-01, there were about 23 minutes of stoppage time in the first-half alone after a broken leg, a dislocated shoulder (Bees striker Lloyd Owusu passed out from the pain and an ambulance had to be driven up to the pitch), and serious concussion caused the delay," noted Will. "In fact, two goals were scored in that first-half injury-time, with the second being clocked in the 67th minute, I believe. The fourth official had originally held up 13 minutes' stoppage time, but one of the injuries occurred in that period to bump it up to 23. I'd be surprised if there were many games that contained more added-on time!"

Is this the longest extra time ever given during a professional football game? And if it isn't, **what is the longest extra time period ever given during a professional football game**?

Comment: @dly it is pretty similar, I guess the only difference is that my question doesn't restrict the football games to be from the top 5 european leagues